# i want asterisk edit only message body (Sdp) i do not need it to edit sip headers

Tags: architecture, asterisk, sip, ims

My problem is when A send invite to Asterisk then asterisk send it to B ,asterisk will change the call-id header and from tag and sdp part .

i need it only change sdp and keep sip headers .

Comment: Asterisk acts as a back-to-back user agent (B2BUA). When A calls B through Asterisk, Asterisk first creates a dialog with A and then a separate dialog with B. The call between A and B is thus divided into 2 (call)legs and Asterisk mediates all SIP signaling between both legs. This should work perfectly fine. Maybe you could explain why you need the call-id and tags to be the same if the current situation isn't what you would like.

Answer (score 0):

Asterisk is NOT sip proxy

It terminate EVERY call coming in and create NEW one call on other leg.

If you want proxy functionality, use more complex proxy staff like kamailio.org